# Bootstrap Grid not working for me

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want 4 columns across the screen on a regular computer monitor and I get 2 across (orders and production) then under production I get the other two. See image below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>DashBoard</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
        <link href="http://localhost/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://localhost/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <button type "button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block ">
                        <a href='/kf_orders_entered_by.php'><font font color="white">Orders!<br><?php include 'bs_kf_orders_entered_by.php';?></font></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <button type "button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block ">
                        <a href='/kf_production.php'><font font color="white">Production!<?php include 'bs_kf_production_price.php';?></font></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <button type "button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block ">
                        <a href='/kf_orders_onhold_dt.php'><font font color="white" >ON Hold<br><?php include 'bs_kf_orders_onhold.php';?></font></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <button type "button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block ">
                        <a href='#'><font font color="white" >Place Holder<br>PlaceHolder</font></a></button></font></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 "> 
                    <div > <?php include 'kf_salesman_total.php';?></div>
                </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkxNr.png)

Comment: It looks like you're not closing your 'col-md-3' div's correctly. The ending div should be right after the ending button tag.

Comment: If you're still having issues, please provide a bootply or jsfiddle so we can tinker

Comment: on bootply it shows up like it should. What would that mean my problem is???????

Comment: on bootply it shows up like it should. so I took out the php include and it works fine so the page I am ask for which is just a total is the problem. I don't have any formating there hmm I don't know what it wou

Comment: why you included 2 times bootstrap.min.css ??

Answer (score 2):

You haven't ending div after `</button>`. (+I fixed some syntax error)
Try the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><a href='/kf_orders_entered_by.php'><font color="white">Orders!<br><?php include 'bs_kf_orders_entered_by.php';?></font></a></button></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><a href='/kf_production.php'><font color="white">Production!<?php include 'bs_kf_production_price.php';?></font></a></button></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block"><a href='/kf_orders_onhold_dt.php'><font color="white" >ON Hold<br><?php include 'bs_kf_orders_onhold.php';?></font></a></button></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"><a href='#'><font color="white" >Place Holder<br>PlaceHolder</font></a></button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3"><?php include 'kf_salesman_total.php';?></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I changed the code, the results are not what I was hopping for still. it put the first three columns on top of each other and the last column is to the right of the middle column of the first three columns that are stack on top of each other.

Comment: If it still appear wrong, then the mistake is in the included php file.

Comment: User is confused of his code. Lot of syntax error. Problem is including php file @kotapeter You are correct from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

SO it has to be the output of this page but what ?????

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connect =odbc_connect("removed");
if(!$connect) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $connect);
}
$gr_total = 0;
$sql="select
SO.ompCreatedBy, count(SO.ompSalesOrderID) as orders,round(sum(SO.ompOrderSubTotalBase),2) as total 
FROM   m1_kf.dbo.SalesOrders SO
Where    SO.ompOrderDate=CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
Group by SO.ompCreatedBy";
$result =odbc_exec($connect,$sql);
if(!$result){
exit("Error in SQL");
}
 while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))
{
  $gr_total = $gr_total + $row['total'];
 }
 $num2 = number_format( $gr_total, 2);
odbc_close($connect);
echo "$num2";
?>
</body>
</html>
```